# Impact of upgrading BlobStorage to general purpose v2 storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

We were already using BlobStorage in Openshift cluster as PVs for applications and for other micro services. I just came to know, Point-in-time restore only supports for general purpose v2 storage account. So, before updgrading to general purpose v2 storage account, I just want to know what are impacts like access URL change for storage account's container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no impacts if `BlobStorage account` is upgraded to `General-purpose v2 account`. The `container / blob urls` are still the same after upgraded.

`General-purpose v2 account` contains **all the features** in the legacy `BlobStorage account`. This is mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#general-purpose-v2-accounts), adding the screenshot of the doc:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue on upgradation to the existing file and objects. It will enable the additional new feature of the v2 version. But if you are accessing application programmatically then you needed to upgrade your package otherwise you may get exception .